# Lighswitch wcf ria service with EF 6

Tags: wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Good day!

I create a WCF RIA Service like described in [this](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/34/Creating-a-Simple-LightSwitch-RIA-Service-using-POCO.aspx) example, but my example work with **EF 6.1** and **`GetAllOrders`** method return a collection from database.

```
public class RiaService : DomainService
{
    [Query(IsDefault = true)]
    public IQueryable<rb17> GetAllOrders()
    {
         var model = new Model1();
        return model.Orders;
    }

    protected override int Count<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.Count();
    }
}
```

After, I create a lightswitch project, add datasource as my WCF RIA service and add screen.
But when I run a project, list screen return error:
 **`"Unable to load data. Please check your network connection and try loading again."`**.

Please explain me, where must I initialize connection? On my WCF RIA Service in method **`GelAllOrders`**, everything works fine, method return collection as queryable when I set break point. In class **`Model1`** already added connectionstring. Why LS request another connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking a couple of things:

1. Does the *Model1* class return an *IQueryable*<*rb17*>?
2. Also does the *rb17* class itself have a unique ID property (with the *Key* attribute) that is populated for each record?

Without a unique ID property, LightSwitch **will** have problems with the entity, but it usually doesn't result in the error you mention. However, that error can be caused by **many** different things, it can be extremely difficult to track down.

The fact that you're using EF 6.1 shouldn't be a problem. It doesn't matter to LightSwitch **how** you create your entities, as long as they satisfy those two rules I mentioned above. Database connectivity is a common cause of that error, but when you debug you say that you can see the records being created?

Answer (score 0):

It is work.

Problem solved by add initialize connection string of model context to constructor.

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
    {
        const string temp =
            @"data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=TestDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = temp;
        Database.SetInitializer<Model1>(null);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```